# VBA multiple checkboxes to control multiple pivot tables

Tags: vba, checkbox, pivot-table

again I need little help which I will greatly appreciate.

Basically, on my dashboard page I have couple of checkboxes that control numerous of pivot tables in the background.

I have checkboxes that are called "definite", "tentative", "pending,", ... and also corresponds to values in pivot fields.

and I have numerous of pivot tables called: "Hidden_1" or "Hidden_2" in different sheets but all with the same structure.

My idea was that If someone checked "definite", it will be selected in all pivot pivot tables in fields called "Status". If someone "unchecked" this checkbox, the pivots will react.

To do so I used a code that I create before and it was working well:

```
    Sub checkbox1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next  
Dim pt As PivotTable, wks As Worksheet
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In wks.PivotTables
        With pt
            If .Name = "Hidden_1" Or .Name = "Hidden_2" Then
                .PivotFields("Status").CurrentPage = "definite"
            End If
        End With
    Next pt
Next wks 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

However, this code selects only one value, so I can't have selected both "definite" and "pending" if someone checked those boxes. Right now all checkboxes has a separate code assigned where only .CurrentPage = "checkboxname" was changed..

I have two questions:

1) what is the best way to select multiple values. E.g. if checked boxes "definite" and "pending" are checked, pivot tables should have selected two values "definite" and "pending" selected in the "Status" field

2) what is the best way to "dis-select" the value? Right now, my procedure checkbox1 is running everytime that the checkbox is clicked. And I want it to run only when I am "checking" it. 
Right now I am trying to link the checkbox with cell, e.g. "definite" has H10, so my code starts with the line:

```
If Range("H10").Value = True Then
'code to select the value in "Status" field
Else
'code to unselect the value in "Status" field
End If
```

I should also noted that I couldn't use ActiveX Checkbox because I had error: "cannot insert object" and I used form controls. I read that this error is somehow connected with a patch that I have installed.

Thank you all for your help,
Matt

Comment: If you want to get rid of the cannot insert object error look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3025036 it will show you how to fix it

Comment: Dear Sam, unfortunately I am not allowed to install any fix and I need to wait until it will be done on corporate level.

Comment: There is a manual desciption of what to do on that link. It involves closes all instances of excel and deleting certain files in temp folders and app data

Comment: I just asked my boss and he didn't let me to do that. anyway, my initial question is still same. I am also working on it so maybe I will be able to do by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on it and found such a solution:

```
Sub checkbox1()
Dim choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6, choice7
Dim oPI As PivotItem
Dim pt As PivotTable, wks As Worksheet

If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B6").Value = "True" Then
    choice1 = "Definite"
End If
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B7").Value = "True" Then
    choice2 = "Tentative"
End If
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B8").Value = "True" Then
    choice3 = "Hold/Option"
End If
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B9").Value = "True" Then
    choice4 = "Pending"
End If
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B10").Value = "True" Then
    choice5 = "Waitlist"
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B11").Value = "True" Then
    choice6 = "Lost"
End If
If Sheets("Hidden").Range("B12").Value = "True" Then
    choice7 = "Cancelled"
End If
Sheets("Hidden_pivot1").PivotTables("Hidden_1").PivotFields("SalesStatus").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Hidden_pivot1").PivotTables("Hidden_3").PivotFields("SalesStatus").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Hidden_pivot2").PivotTables("Hidden_2").PivotFields("SalesStatus").ClearAllFilters
Sheets("Hidden_pivot2").PivotTables("Hidden_4").PivotFields("SalesStatus").ClearAllFilters

For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pt In wks.PivotTables
             With pt
                If .Name = "Hidden_1" Or .Name = "Hidden_2" Or .Name = "Hidden_3" Or .Name = "Hidden_4" Then
                    For Each oPI In pt.PivotFields("SalesStatus").PivotItems
                        Select Case oPI.Name
                                 Case choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6, choice7
                                 Case Else
                                oPI.Visible = False
                        End Select
                    Next
                End If
            End With
     Next pt
Next wks
End Sub
```

This work but is so slow. It would be better if the macro could add and delete those items, instead of re-creating the entire choice.